# Why cant I pass a callback array from PHP to jquery via ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a large file, but while I was debugging the problem, I have shrunk it down, to eliminate everything external. Basically I have ended up with this .php file:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['val'])) {
        header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
        echo json_encode(array("The first string", "first"));
    }
?>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'other',
        data: {val: 'text'},
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            alert('Error -> ' + err);
        }
    });
 </script>
```

In the original code, I have PHP and Javascript in different files, so please dont tell me to inherit PHP into javascript like this `<?php ?>`,
I have just researched a lot of materials, and in many people suggest this way.

In this script, an error function is triggered. When I was studding this problem, I found out, that it is triggered, when invalid json is passed.
Here is what I get in the alert box: `Error -> [object Object]`, here is what I get in the console:

```
uncaught exception: out of memory <unknown>
Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: .ajax/v.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/v.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: .ajax/v.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/v.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/v.statusCode(), abort: .ajax/v.abort(), state: .Deferred/d.state(), always: .Deferred/d.always(), then: .Deferred/d.then(), 11 more… }
```

If I change dataType to html, and remove the contentType, I get success function executed. It passes this:

```
["The first string","first"]
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
```

and the rest of code of the page.

I need to recieve a json. Why is this thing not working? Why don't I recieve json?

P.S.
You may notice, that I don't have .php at the end of the url...
I have an .htaccess file, that removes it, so that is not the problem. I was disabling it and using the script with .php, but nothing changes. The PHP code is executed, but I don't get the proper callback...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding an exit after you echo the json so you don't also return the html below to your ajax call.

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['val'])) {
        header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
        echo json_encode(array("The first string", "first"));
        exit; // add exit here so html below is not also returned
    }
?>
```

Comment: Damn, you are a genius!)) I was trying to solve it for about two days, researching and shrinking stuff... And the answer is so simple)) Thanks a lot man)